# Coroutine only firing once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to run a script that will generate a "ramps" upon touch between point a and b. This code receives a list of where the elements of the ramps should be and then instanciates and places them on the screen.

However the coroutine is only running once and I can't understand why. Can anyone give me some advice?

Thank you very much in advance

```
public IEnumerator CreateRamp(List<Vector3> lP, float angle)
{

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= lP.Count)
    {
        Debug.Log("Iteration " + i + " of " + lP.Count + " position is " + lP[i]);
        GameObject item = Instantiate(Resources.Load("floor")) as GameObject;


        item.transform.position = current_Position;
        item.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 360f));

        item.GetComponent<Ramp>().strtPos = item.transform.position;
        item.GetComponent<Ramp>().strtRot = item.transform.eulerAngles;
        item.GetComponent<Ramp>().strtScale = new Vector3(0.4f, 0.4f, 1);

        item.GetComponent<Ramp>().tgtRot = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
        item.GetComponent<Ramp>().tgtPos = lP[i-1];
        i += 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the return of `lP.Count`?

Comment: Not related to your problem but you should call `.GetComponent<Ramp>()` once per loop and save the result in a local variable then have the 5 calls use that variable.

Comment: Are you running this method using StartCoroutine? If you call it as a regular method: CreateRamp(...) it will only get executed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your condition `i <= lP.Count` is true only once. (Maybe `lP.Count == 1`, I think).

The way co-routine works is that, the code inside the `CreateRamp` function is executed across multiple frames.

When you `StartCoroutine(CreateRamp(...))`, it is immediately run until it hits yield statement. It will wait there for 0.2 seconds and will be run again from the statement right after the yield.

In the second execution, it evaluates the condition `i <= lP.Count` again and see that it is `False` => it jumps out of the loop and because it hits the end of the function, that co-routine will be stopped, no more execution in the future.

Comment: The thing is that I am using the Debug.Log line to test if the lP.Count is smaller than two and I get (as it should be) a wide range of results (usually between 1 and 24): The code always runs once.

Comment: lP.Count varies inside the loop, doesn't it? You mean you are running more than 1 co-routine that manipulate the same List<Vector3>, aren't you? If that was the case, could you please post the code of the other co-routines?

Comment: Oh, and maybe you have already known, List<Vector3> is a reference type. That means any changes caused to its content (Add, Remove, Update elements) will be reflected in your CreateRamp(..) as well.

Comment: No, I didn't know of this and that's definetely why I'm getting the error. I'm clearing the contents of the source list as if the list within the coroutine was local to it. Would converting the list to an array before working with it fix the issue? I'll give it a try tonight either way this answered my question, thank you very much

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to be of help ^^

Comment: Converting the list to array using the lP.toArray() method did fix it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Since this function is an IEnumerable it should be treated by other code as a list of `Ramp` objects.  I suspect (there isn't enough of your code to know), that the way you are calling this function is incorrect.

On a side note, with your yield returning a waitforX, It would be better in the long term to either perform the wait outside of this function (where you are calling it from) or at the very least add the wait period as a parameter to the function.  Hard coded values like that will end up biting you later on, especially if your game's code-base grows.  I recommend it be exposed as a setting on your GameObject, so it can be tweaked from the editor.

One other thing, How do you destroy these Ramp objects when you are done with them?  It might be good to consider storing references to them as you create them so you can destroy them later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,as for your side notes I'll put the wait time in the function arguments and I'll  use a GameObject pool instead of instanciating and destroying everything... this is just for the sake of testing.

Comment: As for how I am calling it, I'm simply using the StartCoroutine method from within the touch function with a list of vector3's and the desired angle as arguments  to do this.

Comment: It would be useful to see that code, since that is most likely where the issue is.